# MRTK - can't get the value from UI_KeyboardInputField object

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Hello i am using the **MRTK 2.7.3** and I am trying the read the value from a **UI_KeyboardInputField** object but seems something is wrong on my code

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Experimental.UI;

public void onSubmit()
{
    GameObject username = GameObject.Find("Username");
    UI_KeyboardInputField inputUsername = username.GetComponent<UI_KeyboardInputField>();
    Debug.Log("username" + inputUsername.Text); <<<ERROR
}
```

> **'UI_KeyboardInputField'** does not contain a definition for **'Text'** and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'UI_KeyboardInputField' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Maybe my approach is wrong how can i get the text value from  this field ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`UI_KeyboardInputField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.experimental.ui.ui_keyboardinputfield?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0#definition)

> Only used in Unity 2018.4. No longer used in Unity 2019.3 and later versions (becomes an empty MonoBehaviour and is only around for compatibility) and you can safely remove it if you wish

And also

> A component that can be added to InputField to make it work with Windows Mixed Reality's system keyboard.

Sounds to me like this is/was only a helper component for forwarding the virtual keyboard input and the actual thing is all happening in a usual [`InputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-InputField.html) component attached to the same `GameObject` and you rather want to access the [`.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html) of that one.